# Preserve from splitting results

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

Is there any possible way to SELECT from MYSQL database and preserve from splitting results? I'd like to get all the data from previous day, but it'll be too much, but I also cannot split results:

Select all with certain limit, but do not split (by certain value, i.e. user_id) onto separate results.

EXAMPLE

```
SELECT
ti.id, ti.date, ti.duedate, ti.datepaid,
tii.invoiceid, tii.userid,
tc.postcode, tc.country,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM custom WHERE relid=tc.id) AS vatid
FROM invoices ti
LEFT JOIN invoiceitems tii
ON tii.invoiceid=ti.id
LEFT JOIN clients tc
ON tc.id=tii.userid
WHERE ti.status='Paid'
AND ti.nullmo_no IS NULL
ORDER BY tii.userid AND tii.id
```

Now I get all the results, but I need to split them without breaking userid. For example one SELECT returns 20 results, because there were 15 invoices for user 1, and 5 invoices for user 2, then the next call returns the rest, also with a limit, but not breaking user related group of results:

SELECT
part 1 (all from user 1, all from user 2)
part 2 (all from user 3, all from user 4)

Can this be done in one select statement?

id = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

name = n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10

user_id = 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 // split but not divide

content = c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10

date = yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday, yesterday

The deal is to select all of them, with a limit, but not to split user_id, so: 1. All from yesterday 2. LIMIT if per one or more user_id's there are more results than LIMIT So the limit would be determined by the number of results.

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired output to illustrate your question?

Comment: Anyone? Bueler, Bueler... ?